# Create crystal report at runtime using a remote sql server as data source

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I had my database and applications (web, api & service bus that all create crystal reports at runtime) on the same server.  All worked perfect creating reports at runtime.

Moved the database to a different server, which only allow remote connections from the app server.

For my database connections, all I had to do in my projects was change the server in the connection string from (local) to the ip address of the database server, and it all works fine.

However it seems that to just change the server from (local) to the ip address for the crystal reports does not work (give a "Database logon failed" error)

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but for creating the report locally (before uploading the .rpt to the server) I had to create a connection where the server is set to "local" ( in the data source location).  Since I cannot access the new database remotely from my local machine, I cannot change that)

The code I use look as follow:

```
string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
string database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUser"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"];
var report = new ReportClass {FileName = reportPath};
report.Load();
report.SetDatabaseLogon(user, password, server, database);
var parameterValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue {Value = item.Id};
var parameter = new ParameterValues {parameterValue};
report.DataDefinition.ParameterFields["@id"].ApplyCurrentValues(parameter);
report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I ended up with this that worked (using sql)
Essentially the idea is setting the logon info not just for the report, but also for all subreports.  Would have been nice if one could just do a "foreach subreport in report.." ,but seems not to work that way

```
        public static void SetConnections(ReportDocument report)
    {
        Database database = report.Database;

        Tables tables = database.Tables;

        var crConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo
        {
            ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"],
            DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"],
            UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUser"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"]
        };

        foreach (Table table in tables)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo crLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            crLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnInfo;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(crLogOnInfo);
        }

        Sections crSections = report.ReportDefinition.Sections;
        foreach (Section crSection in crSections)
        {
            ReportObjects crReportObjects = crSection.ReportObjects;
            foreach (ReportObject crReportObject in crReportObjects)
            {
                if (crReportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                {
                    var crSubreportObject = (SubreportObject)crReportObject;

                    ReportDocument subRepDoc = crSubreportObject.OpenSubreport(crSubreportObject.SubreportName);

                    Database crDatabase = subRepDoc.Database;
                    Tables crTables = crDatabase.Tables;

                    foreach (Table crTable in crTables)
                    {
                        TableLogOnInfo crLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                        crLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnInfo;
                        crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crLogOnInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Crystal report on oracle database, in my application i use this code:

`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rpt = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
//reset connection
DBController.LogonEx(DBAlias, "", DBUsername, DBPassword);
//Create the QE (query engine) propertybag with the provider details and logon property bag
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag QE_Details = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();
ConnectionInfo ci = DBController.GetConnectionInfos(null)[0];
//copy from existing attributes except for server name
for (int idx = 0; idx < ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs.Count; idx++)
{
    switch (ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs[idx])
    {
        case "QE_ServerDescription":
            QE_Details.Add(ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs[idx], DBAlias);
            break;
        case "QE_LogonProperties":
            //this is itself a property bag
            CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag logonDetails = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.PropertyBag();
            PropertyBag OLDLogon = (PropertyBag)ci.Attributes[ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs[idx]];
            for (int idx2 = 0; idx2 < OLDLogon.PropertyIDs.Count; idx2++)
            {
                switch (OLDLogon.PropertyIDs[idx2])
                {
                    case "Server":
                    case "Data Source":
                        logonDetails.Add(OLDLogon.PropertyIDs[idx2], DBAlias);
                        break;
                    default:
                        logonDetails.Add(OLDLogon.PropertyIDs[idx2], OLDLogon[OLDLogon.PropertyIDs[idx2]]);
                        break;
                }
            }
            QE_Details.Add(ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs[idx], logonDetails);
            break;
        default:
            QE_Details.Add(ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs[idx], ci.Attributes[ci.Attributes.PropertyIDs[idx]]);
            break;
    }
}
//now replace all existing connections with new one
CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo newConnInfo = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo();
newConnInfo.Attributes = QE_Details;
newConnInfo.Kind = CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CrConnectionInfoKindEnum.crConnectionInfoKindCRQE;
newConnInfo.UserName = DBUsername;
newConnInfo.Password = DBPassword;
foreach (CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.ConnectionInfo oldConnInfo in DBController.GetConnectionInfos(null))
{
    DBController.ReplaceConnection(oldConnInfo, newConnInfo.Clone(true), null, CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.CrDBOptionsEnum.crDBOptionDoNotVerifyDB);
}`

i hope this help