# On using a Crystal Report Viewer with an ASP.NET C# application, prompt for database password

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, crystal-reports

I've created an ASP.NET app in Visual Studio 2013. I can call a Crystal Report connected to Oracle and run it, and it shows on the screen successfully.

The problem is that when I use the Crystal Report Viewer and click on the toolbar to go to the next page, I get a prompt to enter the password again.

Here is the code that is working:

```
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfo crTableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables crTables;

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "myserver";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "myuser";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "mypassword";

            cryRpt.Load("C:\\Crystal\\Test\\TestReport.rpt");

            crTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
            {
                crTableLogonInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
            }

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

I've searched on this for awhile, but the most I could find was how to set the connection to begin with, which I've been successful with. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768461/create-crystal-report-at-runtime-using-a-remote-sql-server-as-data-source/34769112#34769112

Comment: That didn't seem to work as I don't know what DBController.LogonEx is. I tried to use the other guys code as well, which ran, but I still got the same problem -- the report loads, but prompts for a database password when I go to page 2.